# Android "best practice" for team collaboration and development?

Tags: android

we would to pick the community brains on the best and efficient way to do team collaboration on Android mobile development.

1. Does some members work on the modules and turn it into jars and other team members use it?
2. How to split work between developers and UI designers.
3. How to do automated testings.
4. How to effectively do testings on various mobile devices.

Comment: This question will probably find a better home at [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: its an interesting question. I've not seen much in the way of android testing, and I think that's a dangerous place to be. Any insight from experienced teams would be helpful.

Comment: I think this is a very relevant questions for Android developers here instead of programmers.